# How to redirect to external link without quiting current domain?

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I want to redirect to external link without quiting current domain link.

Following is an example of my question :

[https://translate.google.com/translate?
depth=1&hl=ar&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://bookboon.com/](https://translate.google.com/translate?depth=1&hl=ar&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&u=https://bookboon.com/)

As you can see the main website here is google translate and second is bookbone.com
How can we do that with python using a framework like Django2.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the below code in views.py and make URL for that

```
import urlparse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

domain = request.GET['domain'] 
destination = reverse('variable_response',args=['Successful'])
full_address = urlparse.urljoin(domain, destination)
return HttpResponseRedirect(full_address)
```